# How to use redshift adjust color for display

Tags: redshift

I use ubuntu and other Linux distro,all of them can't display color best on my screen as window, i've try copy *icm file in Windows, but can't use it in my ubuntu, when import , it not effect,

So i try use redshift for instead, this is my config file

But my display still not good, can you edit file config for use redshift to adjust color to best as window

````
temp-day=5700
temp-night=4600
brightness-day=1.0
brightness-night=0.75
gamma=0.8
adjustment-method=vidmode
location-provider=manual

[manual]
lat=63.81415
lon=20.41742```? 

I'm use asus x507uaf, screen 1920*1080 hiDPI, itel UHD graphics 620
````

Comment: You haven't provided your OS/release details.   GNOME contains *night light* for modern releases, so unless you disable that, `redshift` & *night light* can fight & neither will work well.  As I use other DEsktops than just gnome, I disabled GNOME's night light & just use `redshift` (next issue I had was fights between redshift-gtk & redshift-qt because of my many desktops, so I selected one & just use that).  You've been vague with details, but that's my 2c.

Comment: The *lon=20.41742```?* bit looks very wrong, but maybe it was a bad copy/paste..

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, about the color temperature set to 4600 is really red to me. You can set it 6500K for both day and night and only set brightness lower than the day. Here's an example, if you are interested into photograph or the same kind of work, it means a lot.